# log4j2 in Tomcat8 App works in IDE (Eclipse) but not in Production environment (RHEL8)

Tags: java, logging

I have a Tomcat 8.5 Webapp that I've developed.  In Development I run Tomcat (8.5) via my IDE (Eclipse), and the logging configuration is picked up from `WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties`

When I build the War and deploy to our RHEL8 servers running Tomcat8.5, there is no log file created at all.

I presume there is some kind of classpath difference that's leading to this behaviour; but how do I diagnose the issue?

Included in my WebApp are the logging jars:

```
log4j-core-2.15.0.jar
log4j-jcl-2.15.0.jar
log4j-api-2.15.0.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.15.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
```

I've tried logging in my app using both:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

...
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
log.info("Application Initialised");
```

and:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DashboardBean.class);
log.info("Test");
```

but neither one results in the file being created

log4j2.properties:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = tms.log

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = tms-backup-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 50

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = com.mycompany
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Comment: Is it possible that the application doesn’t have permission to write into the current directory? Are you capturing the standard output and standard error streams from the process? They might contain additional details.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I did `chmod a+rwx` recursively on the Tomcat dir.  The standard `catalina.out` doesn't provide anything useful that I can see